# Can outdated drivers cause a DVD RW to read but not write to discs?

Tags: dvd, dvd-burning

I tried two different DVD+-RW drives on a dozen of new DVD-R discs and non of them were burned successfully. Both devices can read discs, but not write to them.

I tried installing fresh copies of both Windows 7 and Windows 10 and installed all the Updates. Nothing changed.

Device manager is saying that I have the latest drivers and I've been unable to manually find any.

Comment: Anecdotally, CD/DVD drives are the parts I have had to replace most often on my PCs over the years (next to hard drives).

Comment: @Anaksunaman Although not impossible, it is highly unlikely that they would sell a damaged device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is *highly* unlikely that drivers are the issue.  The driver essentially tells Windows hot to communicate with the device.  CD, DVD, and Blu-ray devices are just ATAPI devices, which is standard.  They are so standard, they all use the same driver.  You would only need a different driver, if the device offered some non-standard functionality - which I have yet to see.

Most likely the cause of the failure is the media itself.  Optical disc media does degrade over time, especially writable media.  It could also be the writers themselves have some defect, such as the laser is misaligned or dirty.  It is impossible to say, without testing each individual component against known working components.

Also, CD, DVD, and other optical media are discs, with a "C," not disks with a "K."

Comment: The disCs are brand new, bought specifically for this purpose, produced by HP. I'll accept it not being about the drivers. Thanks.